# How to create a 3D model of a person's veins using ultrasound?

Tags: ultrasound

How to create a 3D model of a person's veins using ultrasound? How to do something like this, [CARTOSOUND® Module](https://www.biosensewebster.com/products/carto-3/cartosound-module.aspx):

> This 3D ultrasound technology gives you all the benefits of traditional intracardiac echo

- Why is most ultrasound 2D?
- Is 3D ultrasound a separate technology from 2D?